# How can the fields in this code union with different name?

Tags: sql, oracle

How does this code union even though the column names are different? Does that not matter? It is in a sub-select. Thanks

```
select Distinct AD.MEME_CK
      ,MECD_EFF_DT as EFF_DT
      ,MECD_MCTR_AIDC AS PG_DESC
    from fac.CMC_MECD_MEDICAID AD
    INNER JOIN FAC.CMC_MEME_MEMBER ME
      ON ME.MEME_CK = AD.MEME_CK
    INNER JOIN FAC.CMC_GRGR_GROUP GR
      ON GR.GRGR_CK=ME.GRGR_CK
    INNER JOIN fac.CMC_MCTR_CD_TRANS TR
    ON TR.MCTR_VALUE=MECD_MCTR_AIDC
    AND MCTR_ENTITY='MDAG' AND  MCTR_TYPE='AIDC'
    where ((MECD_MCTR_AIDC IN ('DE8T', 'DEPB', 'DEPC', 'DEPD', 'DEPE', 'DEPF', 'DEPL', 'DEPS', 'DEPT','DEX3','DE8T'))
    or (UPPER(MCTR_DESC) LIKE '%PREG%' and MECD_EFF_DT > sysdate-30 AND GR.CICI_ID IN ('OK','NC','FL','CA')))
      AND sysdate BETWEEN MECD_EFF_DT AND MECD_TERM_DT 






    UNION
/*Member Heatlh Detail Table*/
    select Distinct MEME_CK
    ,MEHE_LAST_DT
    ,MEHE_IPCD_ID
    from fac.CMC_MEHE_HEALTH_DETL D
    WHERE ((MEHE_IPCD_ID IN ('PDRN', 'PRED','PRET','PREG','TAPG') AND MEHE_LAST_DT>sysdate-30)
                 OR (UPPER(MEHE_COMMENT) LIKE '%PREG%' AND MEHE_LAST_DT>sysdate-30)
                 or (MEHE_IPCD_ID='EDOB' and MEHE_LAST_DT>sysdate)
                 or (MEHE_IPCD_ID='LATC' AND substr(MEHE_COMMENT,1,4) IN ('013-','053-','104-','127-') AND MEHE_LAST_DT>sysdate-30))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE):

> The corresponding expressions in the select lists of the component queries of a compound query must match in number and must be in the same data type group (such as numeric or character).

They do not have to have the same names - that isn't important. For the final projection Oracle uses the expression names/aliases from the first branch; you don't have to give subsequent branches aliases at all. So it's fine to do something like:

```
select 42 as some_col from dual
union all
select 5/7 from dual;

  SOME_COL
----------
        42
.714285714
```

Also [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html) (emphasis added):

> The set operators combine the rows returned by two SELECT statements into a single result. The number and data types of the columns selected by each component query must be the same, but the column lengths can be different. **The names of the columns in the result set are the names of the expressions in the select list preceding the set operator**.

where "the names of the expressions in the select list preceding the set operator" means the first `select`, before the `union` - what I refer to as the first branch.