# Setting a Default Column Value in Select Statement for TO_CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, select, default-value

Im trying to assign a default column value for a TO_CHAR function.

```
 SELECT
 '1' AS TO_CHAR(N_NAME)
```

I keep getting the error "FROM keyword not found where expected". Can anyone assist?

Comment: Please show the whole statement you're using, and the result you're expecting; if you're querying a table (so `n_name` is a column in that table) then show the table structure and contents too. You can't give a column a variable alias though, that has to be known at parse time. If you want it set at runtime you would either have to use dynamic SQL or let your client do the naming. Normally who/whatever is consuming the output would expect a fixed column name anyway, so maybe adding more context about what you're actually trying to achieve would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT '1' AS "TO_CHAR(N_NAME)"
FROM YourActualTableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `from dual`:

```
SELECT '1' AS "TO_CHAR(N_NAME)"
FROM dual;
```

Note that `TO_CHAR(N_NAME)` is quite suspicious as a column alias.  It suggests that you actually want to reference a column in a table.

Comment: Well im pulling this field from an actual table so the dual wont work. I am using Dual before this select because ive created a temp table thats unioning to this select, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that since im passing the value as a character, i dont need the TO_CHAR anymore. Cant believe i didnt see that before posting this.

```
SELECT '1' AS N_NAME
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: If this is the second branch in a union - which I think is what you described in a comment - then you don't need to give it any alias at all; and if you do then it doesn't have to match - which was the case with the accepted answer. Coincidentally, [this came up a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153603/266304). Selecting from dual will also work, not sure why you discounted that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, an alias isnt needed at all. Just tested it. I didnt test selecting from dual because im selecting from an actual table. Thank you for your input though

Comment: But you aren't selecting from a real table in this branch of the union - or at least, you don't seem to need to. If you do you'll get one row in that query result with '1' for every row in your table. If you select from `dual` then you will just get a single row. If your table only has a single row then it will still be slightly more efficient to use `dual`, because Oracle has internal optimisations for that.